# Why doesnt ONE of my links in the footer work properly?

Tags: pages, links, footer

I have a products page with a couple child pages and in my footer I have the same product categories as links. All the words do work as links except one and there is no difference in paths and I can if I manually go to my site an into products I can still reach that page but not from clicking the link in the footer, why? I only get to a page doesnt exist although I have the page opened in another tab with the exact same url.

This is my footer.php

```
        <div id="footer">
        <a href="http://energyshop.se/produkter/art-meditationer/">Meditationer</a>, <a href="http://energyshop.se/produkter/guidade-upplevelser/">Guidade upplevelser</a>, <a href="http://energyshop.se/produkter/vatten/‎">Energirening & Energidroppar</a>, <a href="http://energyshop.se/produkter/clearings-och-aktiveringar/">Clearings m.m.
    </div>
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

This is the line that doesnt work:

```
<a href="http://energyshop.se/produkter/vatten/‎">Energirening & Energidroppar</a>
```

although its the same as the other and as I mentioend earlier its just the link in the footer that doesnt work (takes me to error page) but I can still go into Products and click the image for the same ur and come to the correct page without error?

Comment: You have some invisible dirt after trailing slash in your invalid link:`%E2%80%8E`. Also it's a very bad practice to hardcode links. And more, it's not a Wordpress question.

Comment: Also, it works when I click that link in your footer. It is missing a trailing slash but that doesn't break the link when I try it.

Comment: Yes I found the "dirt" and got it to work with using dynamic links as shown below, thank you all. But everyone is saying that hardcoded menu is bad practice, but I am not using hardcoded menu? I use the Custom Menu widget under Appearance -> Menu to create and adjust my menu.

Answer (score 2):

It is incredibly bad practice to hardcode urls, almost as bad practice as hardcoded menus.

I ***strongly*** suggest you research [custom nav menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus). It will save yourself a large amount of time in development, and support costs, and it's something to demonstrate to your client to gain kudos.

Hardcoding menus is a major warning sign of poor code, and it reflects badly on you. Having said that not everyone is aware, and I understand this may be new to you, in which case I hope you find it useful.

## The Hardcoded Fix

If you really, really, must hardcode things ( and all the little kittens that die as a result ), at least make it dynamic so that if your sites URL changes, so does the link:

```
<?php echo home_url('/produkter/vatten'); ?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks fo the reply but I AM using a custom nav menu? And for the hardcoded links in the footer I got them to work with the backslashes but I will change this to dynamic. But this is what the client want, clickable links in the footer, so what would be the best way to solve that?

Comment: Why would you not use a nav menu for the footer links? The client doesn't care how you do it, just that it's done